# Prove that the signature of $M=UDU^t=\#\{d\in \mathbb{R}: d>0\}-\#\{d\in \mathbb{R}:d<0\}$ where $d$ is an element of the diagonal matrix $D$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This question comes from a Theorem in Using Algebraic Geometry by Cox et. al.

$M$ is a symmetric matrix with real entries. Let $p_1,\dots,p_d$ be real numbers or complex conjugate pairs. $D$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $h(p_1),\dots,h(p_d)$ where $h$ is a polynomial with real coefficients.

$U$ is of the following form:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
p_1^{n_1}&p_2^{n_1}&p_3^{n_1}&\cdots &p_d^{n_1}\\
p_1^{n_2}&p_2^{n_2}&p_3^{n_2}&\cdots &p_d^{n_2}\\
\cdots\\
p_1^{n_d}&p_2^{n_d}&p_3^{n_d}&\cdots &p_d^{n_d}
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $n_1,\dots,n_d$ are integers. $U$ is invertible. The signature of a matrix $A$ is defined as the difference of number of positive eigenvalues and the number of negative eigenvalues of $A$, denoted by $\sigma(A)$.

I'd like to prove that 
$$\sigma(M)=UDU^t=\#\{h(p_i)\in \mathbb{R}: h(p_i)>0\}-\#\{h(p_i)\in \mathbb{R}:h(p_i)<0\}.$$

The proof in the book just states that since $M$ has real entries and the entries of $D$ appear in complex conjugate pairs, so the above result follows, which I don't see why.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You're missing something: in particular, $U$ needs to be invertible for this to make sense.

Comment: Also: do you know about the spectral theorem for symmetric matrices? Alternatively, if you look up "Sylvester's law of intertia", you'll find a proof of this very fact.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Sorry I forgot to mention that $U$ is invertible. It actually has some other special structure but I guess that is not necessary.

Comment: What is the other special structure?  Is $U$ *allowed* to be an arbitrary invertible matrix?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I'll edit. I thought a general invertible $U$ could work. But maybe not. I'll let you judge.

Comment: Oh, wait, $U$ and $D$ are determined so that $UDU^T = M$, right?

Comment: Also, you never answered the question from my second comment.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Sorry for the confusion. I am still checking the "Sylvester's law of inertia" and see if I can connect the idea. And yes, $U$ and $D$ are known, and satisfy $M=UDU^t$. Thank you!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Just to complete this question, the Sylvester's law of inertia works. Here is a proof I can follow: http://palmer.wellesley.edu/~aschultz/w10/math416/coursenotes_and_handouts/coursenotes_100422.pdf. It turns out that the special structure of $U$ is not necessary. Thank you for the hint.